# Python: os.system() doesn't work when running from browser

Tags: python

I have a shell script that executes some mySQL backups. I want to be able to run these backups from a browser, so I have a python script that calls the shell script using `os.system()`. The script works when run from the command line, but when run by visiting the URL from a browser, the shell script is not run.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os

os.system("/srv/www/server_utils/mysql_backup.sh")

print "Content-Type: text/html\n"
print "mySQL Backups completed."
```

(`print "Content-Type: text/html\n"` is there to prevent a 500 error from being displayed)

Comment: Any error messages on the server?

Comment: Perhaps you could clarify what you mean by "run in the browser"?  Python typically can't run in a browser.  Do you mean it runs on the server, triggered by an action at the browser?

Comment: Please get rid of the trailing semicolons.

Comment: Please elaborate on *how* you are running this i.e., what server, operating system etc.

Comment: Yes, it runs on the server, triggered by an action on the browser.

Comment: OS is Ubuntu 10.04 running Apache 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the backup script requires specific privileges to run (read permission on the DB, write permission on the backup directory, or both), and the web server does not have these privileges. The solution will depend on what operating system is running the server..

Comment: Ubuntu 10.04 running Apache 2. The error log has the following message:

`mysqldump: Got errno 32 on write`

Comment: error 32 means that mysqldump doesn't have access to the file, which was because www-data didn't have write permissions on the directory. I just added write permissions, and that did the trick. Thanks!